# How can I add have a property of a list populated with a unique number when I populate the list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
List<Phrase> cardSetPhrases = App.DB.GetPhrasesForCardSet(cardSetId);
```

The `Phrase` object has an `int Index` property.

Is there some way using LINQ that I could populate this with a sequence number for each row returned from the right hand side?

I did think about something like this:

```
foreach (var x in App.cardSetWithWordCount.Select((r, i) => new { Row = r, Index = i }))
```

But I wondering if there is a more concise way I could do it.

Comment: I know this is a LINQ question, but i think you are better off using `HashSet<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the hash code for each element?

```
cardSetPhrases.ForEach(x => x.Index = x.GetHashCode());
```

For a sequence, I think you need to rely on a separate variable

```
int i = 0;
cardSetPhrases.ForEach(x => x.Index = i++);
```

Comment: Sorry,  I was wanting to get a sequence number as in 1,2,3

Comment: @Alan2 I couldn't think of something less complex.